# Hibernate dynamic number of results per row

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm working on a feature which allow some users to define their own SQL queries and run them on the database.

Basically a query could look like this:

```
1. SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user;
2. SELECT first_name, last_name, id, address, email FROM user.
```

As you can see there may be a different number of columns in the result table.
Is there a way to handle this in Hibernate?

For instance, the basic usage displayed below does not help me in any way because I cannot be sure that each result row has at least 2 columns.

```
Query query = session.getSession().createSQLQuery(queryStr);
ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
while (results.next()) { 
    data.put("firstName", String.valueOf(results.get(0)));
    data.put("lastName", String.valueOf(results.get(1)));    
}
```

Furthermore, I don't think I can use the `select new map` because the users have to run native MySQL queries.

Is there any solution to this?
Thanks in advance for your time and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I do not think that it is a good idea to expose an interface that allows SQL input to users.

Anyway, in your case you could program the SQL result set extraction yourself. There is no need for object relational mapping, if you do not map into objects. You could then go and just check for the existence of the columns and map them right away into your data structure. Nice way to learn plain JDBC. Just for the case you use Hibernate for other issues in your application, you can even mix the approaches.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. The interface will be available only for the dev team. We are generating some statistics based on this queries and it is easier & faster to place them directly in some sort of GUI than modifying the backend. I would prefer to use Hibernate because this results will be persisted as reports. I would like to stick to the architecture and abstractions if possible.

Comment: @Ionut Ok, sounds reasonable. So then, are you querying just the table "users"?

Comment: Thanks for your time! The `users` select was an example. In our specific case the queries are a little bit more complex joining various tables. Basically this queries' results will have a various number of columns. (May be 5 columns or 20) we want to store this results as JSON strings as key pair values. The issue is that I am not able to find a way for hibernate to return the number of columns a result entry has.

Comment: @Ionut Mhh, sounds like you want to use ElasticSearch or something for storing your reports.

Comment: @Ionut I was thinking about it for a while, but can't think of an easy possibility to do this with Hibernate easily. Sometimes a generic requirement needs a generic solution. I'd really go one layer deeper for JDBC.